# where is the code for woocommerce's default order history page in admin section?

Tags: wordpress, post, woocommerce, admin, orders

I have a woocommerce website, and need to modify somethings in the order history page in admin section.  Where is the code/page(s) located at?

I tried right clicking an element in chrome and inspecting, and then "find in path" on root of my wordpress site in phpstorm, but still had no luck on where the code is located...